# Was Judas based on the story of Buddha and Devadatta?

Tags: life-of-jesus, history, judas-iscariot, buddhism

To oversimplify greatly, Devadatta was a cousin of the Buddha when he was teaching his core disciples. Devadatta and the Buddha had many disagreements on things such as Asceticism. This cause and divide to the point Devadatta attempted to kill the Buddha and cause a schism thereafter.

So, *scholars strongly believe Jesus was a Buddhist for a large part of his life, and the facts surrounding Judas are shaky at best.

So answer away!(Asked in Buddhism as well).

Comment: Who "knows that Jesus was a Buddhist for a large part of his life?"  There are dozens of problems with that statement, but perhaps the most fundamental is: Is there any evidence at all that religious traditions from the Far East even made it to Israel at that point in history, much less found a following among the Jews?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be confrontational

Comment: `"...scholars strongly believe Jesus was a Buddhist for a large part of his life"` Which scholars believe this? Your question will probably be closed unless you provide some reputable sources for this.

Comment: I've seen this crackpot theory on a BBC documentary. It hinges on the fact that we don't know what Jesus did from early childhood to around age 30. Supposedly that's when the Jesus went to India to became a Buddhist sage of sorts.

Comment: OP, just read the gospel accounts. Jesus was clearly a Jew and not a Buddhist.

Answer (score 4):

> And concerning the resurrection of the dead, have you not read **that which was spoken by God**, saying to you: I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob? He is not the God of the dead, but of the living. Matthew 22:31-32

Jesus is affirming that he believes in the God of the Jewish patriarchs, Holy men and prophets not the religion of Buddha.

Comment: quoting the Bible is technically not the same as quoting the real historical Jesus, that’s the whole point in this context.  Jesus did not write the Bible and this fact is accepted by the church too.